# How to scripting of Clear Depth in Overlay Camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to script the clear depth of a camera using an overlay?

[image: Camear Component ScreenShot]

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-clearFlags.html) ...? Which Unity version and packages are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KiynL OP is asking how to access/set the `Clear Depth` option via script ... tbh I think this is pretty clear ;)

Comment: @derHugo You are right. The obvious question is that we both know, for example, it's better to have a code that indicates there is no Clear Depth Boolean in the camera and how to get it?

Comment: @derHugo   i using Unity 2021.1.28f1 version. and  URP
 [ UniversalAdditionalCameraData ] This class has ClearDepth as a Property, but it cannot be set because there is no Setter.

Comment: hm maybe the API is lying but there it says it should be a normal public [field](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@14.0/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.CameraData.html#UnityEngine_Rendering_Universal_CameraData_clearDepth), not a read-only property .. could you post your code?